# need to get value of a perticular textView in a Android Table view

Tags: java, android, json, textview, tableview

i am generating a report as The screenshot below.   i am getting the data from Database through JSON using below code. what i want is, when i click and hold A particular BILL_NO , i need to get that selected value. can anybody please help me to get the code for taking Value of Selected BILLNO in this tableview.

[image]

```
if (resultG == null) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "RESULT is NULL----------------------");
        } else {
            //parse json data
            try {
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(resultG);

                TableLayout tv = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
                tv.removeAllViewsInLayout();
                int flag = 1;
                for (int i = -1; i < jArray.length() - 1; i++) {
                    TableRow tr = new TableRow(supply_report.this);
                    tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    if (flag == 1) {
                        TextView f6 = new TextView(supply_report.this);
                        f6.setText("BILL NO");
                        f6.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                        f6.setTextSize(15);
                        tr.addView(f6);

                        TextView b6 = new TextView(supply_report.this);
                        b6.setText("DATE");
                        b6.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                        b6.setTextSize(15);
                        tr.addView(b6);
                        TextView b19 = new TextView(supply_report.this);
                        b19.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                        b19.setTextSize(15);
                        b19.setText("SHOP NAME");
                        b19.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                        tr.addView(b19);
                        TextView b29 = new TextView(supply_report.this);
                        b29.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                        b29.setText("QTY");
                        b29.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                        b29.setTextSize(15);
                        tr.addView(b29);
                        tv.addView(tr);
                        final View vline = new View(supply_report.this);
                        vline.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 2));
                        vline.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                        tv.addView(vline);
                        flag = 0;
                    } else {
                        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.i("log_tag", "id: " + json_data.getString("SUPPLY_DATE") + ", Username: " + json_data.getString("SHOP_NAME") + ", No: " + json_data.getInt("SUPPLY_QTY"));
                        TextView bx = new TextView(supply_report.this);

                        //-----  \+\ - /+/  -----\\
                        final String billno = json_data.getString("BILL_NO");
                        bx.setText(billno);
                        bx.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                        bx.setTextSize(15);
                        tr.addView(bx);

                        bx.setClickable(true);
                       /* bx.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                TableRow tablerow = (TableRow) v.getParent();
                                TextView items = (TextView) tablerow.getChildAt(2);

                                billNoToDelete = items.getText().toString();
                            }
                        });*/




                        billNoToDelete=bx.getText().toString();
                        registerForContextMenu(bx);


                        TextView b = new TextView(supply_report.this);
                        final String stime = json_data.getString("SUPPLY_DATE");
                        String onlyDatePart=stime.substring(0,10);
                        b.setText(onlyDatePart);
                        b.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                        b.setTextSize(15);
                        tr.addView(b);

                        TextView b1 = new TextView(supply_report.this);
                        b1.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                        b1.setTextSize(15);
                        String shopNm = json_data.getString("SHOP_NAME");
                        b1.setText(shopNm);
                        b1.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                        //-----
                        //---------
                        shopnameTodelete=shopNm;

                        tr.addView(b1);
                        TextView b2 = new TextView(supply_report.this);
                        b2.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                        String qnty = String.valueOf(json_data.getInt("SUPPLY_QTY"));
                        b2.setText(qnty);
                        b2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                        qtyToDelete=qnty;
                       // b2.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
                        b2.setTextSize(15);
                        tr.addView(b2);
                        tv.addView(tr);
                        final View vline1 = new View(supply_report.this);
                        vline1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1));
                        vline1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                        tv.addView(vline1);
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data" + e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "JsonArray fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```
bx.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            TextView tv = (TextView)v;
            String selectedValue = tv.getText().toString();
            return false;
        }
});
```

Comment: thanks for reply, you mean 'b6' or 'bx' ? am getting compliation error as'variable bx is accessed within class, need to make it final'

Comment: any TextView that you want to get value

Comment: thanks @Amy, it is wokring after making 'bx' as Final.

Answer (score 1):

Register a longClick listener with [setOnLongClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnLongClickListener(android.view.View.OnLongClickListener)) on each view that must respond to that gesture.  Give each individual listener the value that is appropriate for that particular view in the constructor to the listener.

I'd recommend not reading a string out of a TextView and prefer reading it directly from the data used to generate the views.